# absolute position with % width, inside a ul li?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm building a navigation menu where I use a regular `ul#nav`.

In my example bellow I'm trying to make the div inside the `li#third` hang over the bottom of the `ul#nav`. I know I need to use `position: absolute` on the div inside `li#third` but if I do that then it just takes up the 100% of the width assigned to it.

I tried changing the `position: absolute; width: 40%;` on the div but then the last `li` slides under it.

How can I keep the width the same as the `li#third` element and still have it flow over it at the bottom?

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/VyHJR/24/

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="first"><a href="">item</a></li>
    <li id="second"><a href="">item</a></li>
    <li id="third"><div id="search">search</div></li>
    <li id="fourth"><div id="flag"><div id="flag_item">4</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
ul#nav { width: 600px; background-color: #fdd; padding: 0; margin: 30px 0 0 20px; overflow: hidden; }

ul#nav li { float: left; text-align: center; }
ul#nav li a { color: #333333; }

ul#nav li#first { background-color: #dff; width: 20%; padding: 6px 0; }
ul#nav li#second { background-color: #ddf; width: 20%; padding: 6px 0; }
ul#nav li#third { background-color: #dfd; width: 40%; }
ul#nav li#fourth { background-color: #ffd; width: 20%; }

li#third div#search { width: 100%; background-color: #333333; height: 40px; color: #ffffff; }
li#fourth div#flag { width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #333333; }
li#fourth div#flag div#flag_item { width: 1px height: 30px; background-color: red; }
```

Comment: read again and again but every time your question was still same.

Comment: For the record you shouldn't have used the same `id`s in your jsfiddle for the `li` items as an `id` can only appear once on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/VyHJR/34/

Now I understand what you were trying to do, it makes sense.

I removed `overflow: hidden` on `ul#nav`, which I assume was there to contain the floats, and replaced it with `display: inline-block`. I could also have used [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

I added `position: relative; height: 1px;` to `ul#nav li#third`. Some `height` was required, otherwise the fourth `li` takes the place of the third. `position: relative` to contain the absolutely positioned `div#search`.

I added `left: 0` to `div#search` purely to fix IE7.

Comment: I had done thought the same thing roughly, but then I realised I that I think he wants the third item to effectively hang over the bottom of the ul. Also in both your examples the 4th `li` is hidden.

Comment: yep thats right i want it to hang over the third. like the top example its some pixles higher then the rest, its that what i want to "flow over"

Comment: @Dejan.S: So, you're only setting `position: absolute` so that the third `li` can "hang over" the bottom of the `ul`?

Comment: nice, so its the `left: 0;` `and height: 1px;` that really does it right? Why does the left play a part here?

Comment: great answer, it makes sense now that i look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
li{ overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;}
```